# How can one design User Experience?

Tags: terminology, ux-field, ux-designer, experience

This question is bit off but I always wondered about this. here it goes, how can one call himself as an **UX Designer**?, when it is a feeling which is experienced by the end user, not like creating an actual thing. how can one design this feeling? one can work on creating this feeling. rather he can call himself as an **UX Expert** which makes sense to me.

It sounds wrong to me calling it **UX Design**, where as term **UI Design** makes perfect sense. can someone explain/enlighten me if I am wrong?.

Comment: This is where common usage and literal interpration of terms differ. This was an issue previously, but I think now people have largely moved past it. See from 2008: http://zurb.com/article/155/user-experience-design-does-not-exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*experience* - (n.) practical **contact with** and observation of facts or events.

*design* - (n.) **purpose, planning, or intention** that exists or is thought to exist **behind an action**, fact, or material object.

---

Seems like you could argue that a user's **contact with** your application could be **purposefully and intentionally planned**. The "user" modifier is to state that this purposeful design is focused around improving, specifically, the user's experience.